# "File not found" issue when create a folder in a Google shared drive with API

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm trying to create a folder in a shared drive with google drive API v2.1.3. My script works wonderfully to create a folder in my personal Drive but as soon as I put the identifier of a shared drive, I constantly get a "File not found"... I specify that I have given the permissions for my service account in the shared drive...

My code :

```
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig($chemin_idendifiant_google_drive_api);
    $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');

    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
    $parent = '1-FzaEgtKFZ6XXXXXXXXXXkjcbtiDKZEQ'; //Folder in my shared drive

    //Create new folder
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
        'name' => 'Test Folder',
        'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',   
        'driveId' => $parent,
        'parents' => array($parent)
    ));

    $optParams = array(
        'fields' => 'id',
    );

try {
    $createdFile = $service->files->create($file, $optParams);
    print "Created Folder: ".$createdFile->id;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception reçue : ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

I have read that the "supportsAllDrives" attribute should be used, however on the documentation it is noted that it is deprecated since June 1, 2020 (https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Drive_Files_Resource.html#_create)

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 2):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => 'Test Folder',
    'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',   
    'driveId' => $parent,
    'parents' => array($parent)
));

$optParams = array(
    'fields' => 'id',
);
```

#### To:

```
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => 'Test Folder',
    'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
    'parents' => array($parent)
));

$optParams = array(
    'supportsAllDrives' => true,
    'fields' => 'id',
);
```

#### Note:

- When you don't have permission to the folder of `$parent` as the writer, an error occurs. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for your quick response, I got the following error: (create) unknown parameter: 'supportsAllDrives'
On the other hand, I thought I read on the documentation that the 'supportsAllDrives' attribute was deprecated...

My service account has write access to the shared drive.

Comment: @Ennaej Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `I thought I read on the documentation that the 'supportsAllDrives' attribute was deprecated...`, in this case, `supportsTeamDrives` is deprecated. `supportsAllDrives` can be used. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) And, when I tested my proposed script, I could confirm that no error occurs and a new folder is created to the specific folder of the shared drive. I apologize for this. So, can you confirm your script again? By the way, the version of Drive API you are using is v3?